# In Powershell on Windows7, how do I automatically set aliases (or run scripts) when powershell loads?

Tags: powershell, alias

I have created a powershell cmdlet and assigned it to an Alias. How do I do this automatically every time powershell launches? (i.e. so I don't have to re-assign the alias every time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a profile.

This is a `.ps1` script that will be run before you get the prompt.

You can have three per-user profiles, all in the `WindowsPowerShell` folder under your default documents folder.

- `profile.ps1`: always run first.
- `Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1`: run second for ISE.
- `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`: run second for console instance.

The second file to be run is given by `$Profile` in the applicable instance (and will give you the folder for all of them).

See `help about_profiles` for more details.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for the answer. I couldn't open my Documents&Settings in Windows7 for some reason, but I managed to edit profile.ps1 in c:\windows\system32\windowsPowershell\v1.0\

Works like a charm.

Comment: That's because "Documents and Settings" isn't a folder in Windows Vista/7. It's a symlink (not accessible using Explorer) that points to "Users" folder.

Comment: @willem, @Hello71: To change to your user profile folder: `pushd (split-path $profile)`. If the folder doesn't exist this will fail, so you might need: `md (split-path $profile)`

Comment: the global one no longer works in Win8.